# How can I use Java's constants value as th:value name?

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I have a constant for a name.

```
public static final NAME_SOME = "some"
```

In my html I tried,

```
<input th:value="${T(the.package.TheClass).NAME_SOME}"/>
```

I expected the actual value from the model named by `some`.
Yet I see `value=some`.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bit unclear what you're asking.  The expression `<input th:value="${T(the.package.TheClass).NAME_SOME}" />` should indeed evaluate to `<input value="some" />`.  You mean you have a form with a model object and you want to bind it to the expression `model.some`?  You can use preprocessing to do that, I think...

```
<input th:field="*{__${T(the.package.TheClass).NAME_SOME}__}" />
```